# How can I download Java SE 6, Update 121?

Tags: java, java-6

I need JDK6 for running a legacy application. But I need TLS 1.2 support also.

[This link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#R160_121) says TLS 1.2 support is available in Java™ SE Development Kit 6, Update 121. But [the java archive download page for ver 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) has versions 45 and lower only.

Can I download the specified version of JDK from aome other page in oracle website? Is such a provision available?

Comment: *Can I download the specified version of JDK from some other page in oracle website?* - If you find such a site, and you do it, that is a copyright violation, both by yourself and the person who runs the site.  Just don't. do it.  Oracle have expensive lawyers and deep pockets!

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be a supported customer to get more recent patches of old jdk versions. See [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html):

> Current update releases for JDK 6 and JDK 7 are available for support
>   customers.

Comment: Only versions through 6u45 are available via this link, which the poster made clear. The poster is asking about 6u121, which is an advanced version.

Answer (score 5):

*Java SE* is free but *Java SE Advanced* is not free. You have to purchase it from Oracle. See this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/products/index.html) for more info.

`6u121` is a Java SE Advanced version.