# How to enable TLSv1.2 in JAVA 7u80 client

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2

We have a java application which runs on `Java Version: 1.7.0_80` and we are trying to enable `TLSv1.2` with the jvm argument `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true 
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true` to consume a web service which supports only `TLSv1.2`. Though we have the jvm argument java client still using `TLSv1` for communicating with web services,

[image] can someone please help me is there any jvm configurations I need to make to use TLSv1.2 without any code change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable TLS 1.2 in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157422/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-in-java-7)

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with just configuration changes in my case, without code change

Comment: As I understand, no. You have to either update your java 7 to the latest patch (I guess it is 131) or make code change.

Comment: @SergeiSirik : not really a duplicate. In the question you mention, no answer gives the real reason why it was not working : ""jdk.tls.client.protocols system property. This propery has been available since Java SE 7u95."

Comment: its a https protocol for webservice call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any code change, as I wrote in the comment, you need at least [7u95](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).

> jdk.tls.client.protocols system property. To enable specific SunJSSE
>   protocols on the client, specify them in a comma-separated list within
>   quotation marks; all other supported protocols are then disabled on
>   the client. For example, if the value of this property is
>   "TLSv1,TLSv1.1", then the default protocol settings on the client for
>   TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 are enabled on the client, while SSLv3, TLSv1.2, and
>   SSLv2Hello are disabled on the client. This propery has been available
>   **since Java SE 7u95**.

The same property is also available since Java 6u121, with Java 6 supporting and implementing TLS 1.2.

Comment: Java 7u95 is available only for business users. Not available for simple users. I guess question was originally about how to enable TLSv1.2 in Java 7u80.
Can anyone help on enabling TLSv1.2 in 7u80?

Comment: The question was indeed for 7u80 and if you cannot upgrade you need a code change (one of the solutions given by Sergei Sirik's link above).

Comment: Unfortunately the code provided in the link is working only for sql authentication. Not for windows authentication.

Comment: The question is about enabling TLS 1.2. If you have difficulties with Windows authentication, either provide code and raise a question on SO, or ask on ServerFault.

Comment: It appears that Java 6u161 is a 'Java SE Advanced version', and therefore only available to paying customers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859426/how-can-i-download-java-se-6-update-121

Comment: @PerLindberg You probably wanted to say 6u121 and you are right. Are there still Java 6 users around ?

Comment: Yes, 6u121, that's right. And yes, I'm currently stuck with Java 6 / Glassfish 3.1.2.2 for now. So I need to somehow transplant TLS 1.2 to it.

Comment: @PerLindberg You need TLS for running as a client or as a server ? As a server maybe just putting a reverse proxy in front of Glassfish would fit your need ?

Comment: It's for Glassfish application server. TLS 1.2 must be supported by March 2020, when the major browsers cease to support TLS 1.1. A reverse proxy (e.g. Apache) is a cool workaround, but won't do in my particular case.

Comment: @PerLindberg I don't have the Glassfish source code to check how it's calling SSL classes. From what I know and tested on simple programs, you can install the BouncyCastle provider and get Java 6 running with TLS 1.2. It takes 15 minutes to download the jar files, edit java.security, and restart your server. Please let us know if this worked.

Comment: Eugène, thanks for the suggestion. Took more than 15 minutes, though, since I'm not familiar with this particular kind of magic. :-) I downloaded and installed bc_fips-1.0.2.jar in ...jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/ext and added '     security.provider.9=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider' to ...jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/security/java.security. Then I restarted Glassfish. No joy; the browser still warns about deprecated version of TLS. Perhaps there's some missing setting in my Glasfish Admin Console...

Comment: @PerLindberg I think you need bcprov-jdk15to18-164.jar (and bctls-jdk15to18-164.jar ? ) rather than the fips one, and add the provider in first position then it comes before SUN JSSE . All this is experimental. Where can we download the same Glassfish as yours ?

Comment: I tried with bcprov-jdk15to18-164.jar (from https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) and added security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider to java.security (and renumbered the existing providers). Did not help. There doesn't seem the be a .jar file with bctls-jdk15to18-164, only a .tar.gz file with sources. I didn't have to use it, since Glassfish starts without it.
Glassfish 3.1.2.2 can be downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/ogs-v3122-downloads.html

Comment: @PerLindberg Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50489592/7748072) which shows how to declare the provider. Check again, I can see [bctls-jdk15to18-164.jar](https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bctls-jdk15to18-164.jar) on the latest releases page.

Comment: Thanks again, @Eugène. I installed bctls-jdk15to18-164.jar and configured the two bouncycastle providers in java.security. It _probably_ made Java TLS work, but Glassfish fails. Connection attempts result in the log message
`org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer
Server raised fatal(2) bad_record_mac(20) alert: Failed to process record
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: bad_record_mac(20)`
Also, changing to `ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX` didn't help. Presumably some more esotheric Glassfish magic is needed.

Comment: @PerLindberg Two things could maybe help : adding -Djavax.net.debug=all and a network capture. Maybe, open a new question here, because your question is more about Glassfish than TLS1.2 on legacy JVM. Keep us informed