# TLSv1.2 on Jboss 5.1.0 GA using Java 6 and BouncyCastle

Tags: bouncycastle, tls1.2, jboss5.x, java-6

I'm facing a problem with a Jboss server and the https connector, running on Java 6.
I want to make my server using only TLSv1.2 and using the cipher suites "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" for decoding the certificate.

I know that Java 6 does not support TLSv1.2, but I added the Bouncy Castle JCE and JSSE provider to the JDK (https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) :

- Added the JARs files (***bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar*** and ***bctls-jdk15on-159.jar***) in **path_to_jdk/jre/lib/ext** folder
- Edited file ***path_to_jdk/jre/lib/security/java.security*** to add lines :

  *security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
  security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider*

The java instruction : ***SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");*** does not throw a NoSuchAlgorithmException anymore if I test it on a small test class.

On Jboss :

- Edited file ***path_to_jboss/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml*** to have :

  < Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
          port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
          keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/jboss.pfx"
          keystorePass="password" **sslProtocols="TLSv1.2"** maxThreads="170"/>

After that, jboss is still providing only SSLv3 and TLSv1 protocols for https connection.

Any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the 'sslProtocols' attribute translates to a call to SSLParameters.setProtocols (later given effect by SSLSocket.setParameters), and doesn't affect the SSLContext.getInstance call. So you are still getting a SunJSSE SSLContext because you added BCJSSE at lower priority.

I suggest moving the BouncyCastleJsseProvider entry in java.security to a higher priority (than com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider).

Also in java.security you will need to set the default KMF type from SunX509 to PKIX (change the existing entry):

```
ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX
```

This is because BCJSSE currently only works with its own KMF implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !!

You're right, moving the BC provider before sun Provider in security provider list and changing KMF algorithm to PKIX worked !

Thank you again :)

Comment: I've got `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKIX KeyManagerFactory not available` as a result...