# TLS 1.2 support with java6

Tags: java-6

I need JDK6 for running a legacy application. But I need TLS 1.2 support also.  But TLS 1.2 support is available in Java™ SE Development Kit 6, Update 121 or 111. and the java archive download page for ver 6 has versions 45 and lower only.  How can I get it please help?

Answer (score 1):

Older archived version are available only from oracle support login.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Note : 
If you are facing any memory issues with specific to the version 121 or 111 please try below options.

- jdk 1.6u191
- jdk 1.6u141
- jdk 1.6u115 b32

Answer (score 1):

Old, yet still relevant.
Jdk 6u45 is the last free SE (Standard Edition) build available.
Any version above that, in JDK 6, would be a SE Advanced version, which has a price tag.

Please refer to this answer:
[How can I download Java SE 6, Update 121?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859426/how-can-i-download-java-se-6-update-121)

And here's a topic about using Bouncy Castle library, updating Java Cryptography Extension (JCE), amongst other steps, to enable TLS 1.2 in JDK 6 (u45):
[How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6)